# Single and Double Backslash in Path

Tags: html, css

I have tried everything to get a background image to work but have had no luck.

- I'm using most current versions of Windows and IE.
- Works fine server side.

**Does anyone have an example?**

*Note:* The `img` tag in the body renders the image just fine.

also tried background:url...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 html { height:100%; width:100%;
        background-image:url("file://C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\florida-orlando-resort.jpg");
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 123...<img src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\florida-orlando-resort.jpg"
        style="width:100px; height:100px; display:cover;">...456
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Use a single Forward-slash `/` like `C:/Folder/Images/image.jpg` (**preferred**)
**2.** Escape your backslashes `\\` like `C:\\Folder\\Images\\image.jpg`

Theoretically you should escape also the backslashes that you use in image's `src`:

```
<img src="file://C:\\Folder\\Images\\image.jpg">
```

(or again use simply a single `/`).
Due to some *[accidents](https://superuser.com/questions/176388/why-does-windows-use-backslashes-for-paths-and-unix-forward-slashes)* in programming history **Windows** paths uses `\`. You would normally access your image using: `C:\Folder\Images\image.jpg`.
Browser gateways tries to normalize that issue for you and looks like it works in HTML syntax. CSS style instead (I believe the way it's parsed) needs to follow the [escaping directive](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri) for *unwise* characters (`\`) translating it to a Windows understandable path.

I encourage you to simply forget about `\` and use it the way you'd do on a live server:

```
background-image: url("C:/Folder/Images/image.jpg");
```

and respectively in HTML

```
src="C:/Folder/Images/image.jpg"
```

An additional note is that you should preferably use lowercase folder names.

P.S: from *file:* environment on Windows (NTFS filesystem) an all-lowercase path might match the desired file, but the same might not work on a live server. Such mistake might lead to small headaches, so try always to use *lowercase*

Comment: That worked. I don't get the different between the img tag and file reference. Thank You!!!